# How to decode attributes of an nft in rust?

Tags: rust, nft

i use the mpl_token_metadata in my rust program to get the metadata of an nft. So i can get the URI of the json file for this nft.
Then, is there a way in rust to read this uri and decode the JSON to read the NFT's attributes ?
(i could do it in JS, but i feel this is not secure enough)
Thanks in advance !

Comment: There's some ambiguity in the question in the sense that you could be asking both about decoding attributes on-chain (via a smart contract), or off-chain (using a client written in Rust), could you clarify which one it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**: I left a comment asking to clarify whenever we are talking about an on-chain program or an off-chain client. The answer below assumes we are talking about an on-chain program.

TL;DR, As it stands right now, that's not possible.

The attributes of an NFT are hold in an external storage unit, usually Arweave. This means that this data, looking at it through Solana's perspective, is off-chain. And you can't access off-chain data in a smart contract.

If you think about it, you'd need to do an HTTP(s) petition to Arweave to download the json file with the attributes, but there's no IO layer on the Solana chain to do so.

The reason why there's no IO layer is because IO is not deterministic, and executables on-chain must be [deterministic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_algorithm), so they can run exactly the same on all the nodes.

I wonder if it would be possible using [GenesysGo new storage service](https://shdw.genesysgo.com/), since the information is stored on Solana and I presume it is accessible via accounts. But this service is very new and I haven't looked at it yet, so if anyone has more information on this, I would love to hear it!

So, if you really wanted to access it for some reason, You'd need to find a way to replicate the attributes information on-chain, using a custom smart contract.

Comment: ok thank you very much for your reply. Yes i was speaking in an onchain program. I would like to have different program behavior depending on NFT attributes, so i guess i must get them thru JS, and then call rust with the info i need. But to me that seems a security breach, since anyone could call the program with a custom argument then.

Comment: Yep, I'm not sure if this would work for your use-case, but you can write down a different program ( let's call it `P2`) first, where you provide the attributes information and the mint address and you store all of that in a PDA (let's call it `A1`). Then you loop call `P2` to register all NFTs. Then in your program, you send both the mint account (`M1`) and the `A1` account. That way you would have access to the attributes and you would be able to verify that `A1` and `M1` are related via the mint address. Sorry if it's not really clear, this comment system doesn't allow for much expression><

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to fetch an external URI on-chain, because this is not deterministic.

You could create your own attributes PDA and store it on chain for each NFT.